# How to trigger a refresh on a VIEW when an associated table's data is changed

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers, android-sqlite

An SQLite `View` only refreshes its data when it's queried. I need the `View` to refresh its data when one of the view's associated tables gets updated.

How do I write a trigger to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand an idea behind database views. If you need refreshed data from the view, query it again. It's as simple as that.

Comment: "An SQLite View only refreshes its data when it's queried." - I understand this.

I am using `SqlBrite` to keep my UI informed of changes in the underlying data. But it's based on a View - not a Table, which may be causing some issues. A better comment from you would have been about writing a trigger that would query the view automatically in order to refresh it. Something like `SELECT null FROM VIEW`

Comment: Trigger for SQLite or for something else? Cause trigger in SQLite has nothing to do with what you see in your results from the view. On the other hand, trigger for anything else is beyond the scope of SQLite.